# Black Screen after Disk Encryption (after updating to 19.10)

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I just updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 (which has seemed to work, at least I rebooted a couple of times without any issues) to 19.10. Now the Bios splash screen is shown, as well as the screen to decrypt the hard-drive. After entering the correct password the screen goes black. This happens for the internal display of the laptop (Lenovo Thinkpad x220) as well as for the 2 external monitors (connected via dock). I am able to boot into recovery mode, where I can log in with my usual credentials and even WiFi works.

GRUB does not offer me any older Kernels.

Is there a way to get graphical output back? What checks could I run to see what is missing? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

Solved the issue.